# html5 multiple xmlhttprequest more response

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, response

**Hi guys!**

I've got a little problem with my **HTML5 XMLHttprequest** uploader.

I read files with **Filereader** class from *multiple file input*, and after that upload one at the time as binary string. On the server I catch the bits on the input stream, put it in tmp file, etc. This part is good. The program terminated normally, send the response, and I see that in the header (eg with FireBug).
But with the JS, I catch only the last in the '*onreadystatechange*'.

I don't see all response. Why? If somebody can solve this problem, it will be nice :)

You will see same jQuery and Template, don't worry :D

*This is the JS:*

```
function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    var todo = {
            progress:function(p){
                $("div#up_curr_state").width(p+"%");
                },

            success:function(r,i){

                $("#img"+i).attr("src",r);
                $("div#upload_state").remove();
                },

            error:function(e){
                alert("error:\n"+e);
                }
        };


    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();
        var row = $('ul#image_list li').length;
            row = row+i;
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile,s) {
            return function(e) {
            // Render thumbnail.
            $("span#prod_img_nopic").hide();
            $("div#prod_imgs").show();
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.className = "order_"+s+" active";
            li.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" id="img'+s+'" src="', e.target.result,
                                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><div id="upload_state"><div id="up_curr_state"></div>Status</div>'].join('');
            document.getElementById('image_list').insertBefore(li, null);
            };
        })(f,row);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);

        //upload the data
        //@param object fileInputId     input file id
        //@param int    fileIndex       index of fileInputId
        //@param string URL             url for xhr event
        //@param object todo            functions of progress, success xhr, error xhr
        //@param string method          method of xhr event-def: 'POST'

        var url = '{/literal}{$Conf.req_admin}{$SERVER_NAME}/{$ROOT_FILE}?mode={$_GET.mode}&action={$_GET.action}&addnew=product&imageupload={literal}'+f.type;

        upload(f, row, url, todo);
}
```

the upload function:

```
function upload(file, fileIndex, Url, todo, method)
 {
        if (!method) {
            var method = 'POST';
        }

        // take the file from the input

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file); // alternatively you can use readAsDataURL
        reader.onloadend  = function(evt)
        {
                // create XHR instance
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                // send the file through POST
                xhr.open(method, Url, true);

                // make sure we have the sendAsBinary method on all browsers
                XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary = function(text){
                    var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
                    var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
                    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
                    var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)(); 
                    bb.append(data);
                    var blob = bb.getBlob();
                    this.send(blob);
                }

                // let's track upload progress
                var eventSource = xhr.upload || xhr;
                eventSource.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                    // get percentage of how much of the current file has been sent
                    var position = e.position || e.loaded;
                    var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                    var percentage = Math.round((position/total)*100);
                    // here you should write your own code how you wish to proces this
                    todo.progress(percentage);        
                });

                // state change observer - we need to know when and if the file was successfully uploaded
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
                {  
                        if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4)
                        {                                
                            // process success                               
                            resp=xhr.responseText;

                            todo.success(resp,fileIndex);
                        }else{
                            // process error
                            todo.error(resp);
                        }                            
                };

                // start sending
                xhr.mySendAsBinary(evt.target.result);
        };
   }

    }
}
```

and the starter event

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "catch only the last response in onreadystatechange"? What do you expect?

Comment: Does it only look like or do you upload all the files each time a single one changes? And also, you should not [need to] set the ` XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary` method repeatedly - it's a prototype.

Comment: todo.success(..) function set the response into img src. If I upload 3 files, after that I wait for three response (changed src). But only the last response and image change. And if I see the post responses with some program, other response comes too. Do u understand me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a quite small mistake: You forgot to add a `var` statement:

```
    // create XHR instance
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//  ^^^ add this
```

With a `readystatechange` handler function like yours

```
function() {  
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {       
        resp=xhr.responseText; // also a missing variable declaration, btw
        todo.success(resp,fileIndex);
    } else {
        todo.error(resp);
    }                            
}
```

only the latest xhr instance had been checked for their `status` and `readyState` when any request fired an event. Therefore, only when the last xhr triggers the event itself the success function would be executed.

*Solution*: Fix all your variable declarations, I guess this is not the only one (although affecting the behaviour heavily). You also might use `this` instead of `xhr` as a reference to the current `XMLHttpRequest` instance in the event handler.

Comment: wow. thanks your helpfull. it's good. I've not seen this mistake.

Comment: Sometimes the biggest mistakes are also the smallest mistakes. When I was ten, typing in BASIC code from magazines, it was the single character mistakes that got me. Decades later, it is still the little things.